# GatsbyImage not retrieving image data and erroring

Tags: json, typescript, graphql

I am trying to use `GatsbyImage` to render images in a gallery component I am making, where the data is stored in a local JSON file.

I'm not sure why, but when i'm trying to use `getImage` to render the relevant image src path for `GatsbyImage` to work, it errors saying `image undefined` or

```
Type 'IGatsbyImageData | undefined' is not assignable to type 'IGatsbyImageData'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'IGatsbyImageData'.
```

If I go to the image path directly using `item.image.src` it returns the image path set in my JSON file. I've also tried adding this directly to `GatsbyImage` but that errors saying it expects and object, not string.

If anyone could help point me in the right direction with this it would be appreciated.

```
"gallery": [
            {
                "image": {
                    "src": "/static/projects/r24-0.jpg",
                    "alt": "xx"
                }
            },
            {
                "image": {
                    "src": "/static/projects/r24-1.jpg",
                    "alt": "xx"
                }
            },
            {
                "image": {
                    "src": "/static/projects/r24-2.jpg",
                    "alt": "xx"
                }
            },
            {
                "image": {
                    "src": "/static/projects/r24-3.jpg",
                    "alt": "xx"
                }
            }
        ],
```

Query in parent component

```
query Query {
        dataJson {
            cs_r24 {
                gallery {
                    image {
                        src 
                        alt 
          }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Child component rendering the gallery images

```
import React from "react";
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image";


interface Gallery {
    gallery: {
        image: {
            src: string;
            alt: string;
        };
    }[];
};

const ImageGallery = ({gallery}:Gallery) => (
    <div className="image-gallery">
        {
            gallery.map((item, idx) => {
                const image = getImage(item.image.src);

                console.log('image', image);
                return (
                    <div key={idx} className="image-gallery__item">
                        <GatsbyImage image={image} alt={item.image.alt} />
                    </div>
                )
            })
        }
    </div>
);

export default ImageGallery;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your set up, I can see a couple of things. One is the way you are querying your image, should this not be structured as the below:

```js
image {
  gatsbyImageData(placeholder: BLURRED)
}
```

You also have an issue with your type declaration for gatsby image, you need to use the `IGatsbyImageData` export from the plugin:

```js
import { IGatsbyImageData } from "gatsby-plugin-image";

interface SomeImageInterfaceExample {
  image: {
    gatsbyImageData: IGatsbyImageData;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver, but i'm still getting errors. If I add `gatsbyImageData(placeholder: BLURRED)` to the GraphQL query in the parent component I get the following error ` AggregateError: GraphQL Document Validation failed with 1 errors;
  Error 0: GraphQLDocumentError: Cannot query field "gatsbyImageData" on type "DataJsonCs_r24recruitmentGalleryImage".
    at undefined:31:7` due to gatsbyImageData not being in the JSON data object.